# Read and Write of String data to file

Tags: java

How to read and write string data to file using one line code without using **commons-io.jar**  or any other api and

without using complex code BufferedReader and InputStreamReader.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like, it is just syntactical sugar that you are interested in. Here you go:

```
// write
new PrintWriter("the-file-name.txt", "UTF-8").append("this string").close();

// read
String thisStr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("the-file-name.txt")).readLine();
System.out.println(thisStr);
```

Comment: How is that "without using complex code `BufferedReader`..."`?

Comment: And its possibly leaking open streams, bad style at least.

Comment: Exception handling??.. `IOException` ??

Comment: @TheLostMind As for `IOException` - this function (whose part these statments are) may throw one.

Answer (score 2):

How about using classes from `java.nio.file` package

```
String s = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("input.txt")));
```

If you want to write bytes which you got from `readAllBytes` to file you can use

```
Files.write(Paths.get("output.txt"), s.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
```

or without `s` String

```
Files.write(Paths.get("output.txt"),
        Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("input.txt")),
        StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
```

but in this case `Files.copy(source, target, options)` seems better option:

```
Files.copy(Paths.get("input.txt"), Paths.get("output.txt"),
        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: thanks for giving answer, it is available in jdk 1.7 but unfortunately i am working on jdk 1.6 so Files class in not present.

Comment: Well that is quite important information so it should be mentioned in your question :/ (who would guess it in age of Java 8).

Answer (score 0):

You can use following line to read all content of file just in one string.

```
String content = new Scanner(new File(filepath)).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
```

using `java.util.Scanner`

for write operation use

```
PrintWriter printWriter=new PrintWriter("filename").append("content");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a large family of convenience methods in the `java.nio.file.Files` package, such as

- [`readAllBytes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes-java.nio.file.Path-);
- [`readAllLines()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-).

But you should also consider using [`lines()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-), which returns a `Stream<String>`, which will allow you to *lazily* read the lines and process them as you go, without having to load the entire file on the heap.